# Some apps don't show overlay icon in spread mode

Tags: unity, icons

I don't understand why some apps don't show the icon in spread mode, as you can see in the image below:

[Spread mode, apps without overlay icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVlMb.jpg)

I checked the **.desktop** file in /usr/share/applications, and the **.png** file in /usr/share/pixmaps, and everything is ok.

The apps with this problem on my system are:

- Atom
- Slack

Both installed from .deb package.

What can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a comment but I have no idea what I'm looking for in your picture. Plus I don't know what "spread mode" is. I do know there are lots of smart people in AskUbuntu and they will have great answers for you. I wonder though if it's some applications that are misbehaving such as `Atom` and `Stack` (never used them) wouldn't the developer's website be the place to target your question???

Comment: Is a really good comment, I always blame Ubuntu for the problems :-P . I'll give a try with developer's website too. Thanks!